# Entity Framework : Updating an existing child object with a new parent object

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am trying to do a data load using EF and stuck where I can't insert a new record when the child record is existing. Here is an example.

```
public class Position
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string PositionName { get; set; }
}

public class Application
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string ApplicationName { get; set; }
    public Position ApplicationPosotion { get; set; }
}
```

In the above example multiple **Applications** can belong to one **Position**. Assume we already have the **Position** record and if I make the following call, it will fail because **Position with ID 5** is already in the database.

```
    public static void UseEntityFrameWorkOneFail()
    {
        using (var db = new DemoDbContext(@"Server=DESKTOP-HUJVOQ5\SQLEXPRESS;Database=Demo2;Trusted_Connection=True;"))
        {
            Application appOne = new Application
            {
                Id = 7,
                ApplicationName = "AppOne",
                ApplicationPosotion = new Position { Id = 5, PositionName = "ABC" }
            };

            db.Applications.Add(appOne);
            db.SaveChanges();

            appOne = db.Applications.Find(7);
            Console.WriteLine(appOne.ApplicationPosotion.PositionName);
        }
    }
```

Now I can pull that record and make a call like this and get it to work

```
     public static void UseEntityFrameWorkPass()
    {
        using (var db = new DemoDbContext(@"Server=DESKTOP-HUJVOQ5\SQLEXPRESS;Database=Demo2;Trusted_Connection=True;"))
        {
            Application appOne = new Application
            {
                Id = 8,
                ApplicationName = "AppOne",
                ApplicationPosotion = db.Positions.Find(5)
            };

            db.Applications.Add(appOne);
            db.SaveChanges();

            appOne = db.Applications.Find(8);
            Console.WriteLine(appOne.ApplicationPosotion.PositionName);
        }
    }
```

However I want to know if there is an easy way to do this. I am converting JSON to objects and saving for data loading purpose.

All I want is if the child record exists (in this case **Position**), then just update it with the new values. **An Upsert**

```
            Application appOne = new Application
            {
                Id = 7,
                ApplicationName = "AppOne",
                ApplicationPosotion = new Position { Id = 5, PositionName = "123" }
            };

            db.Applications.AddOrUpdate(appOne);
            db.SaveChanges();
```

The above example where I am using AddOrUpdate will do the Upsert for the parent object but not the child object. I want the child object also to be updated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
var appPosotion = db.Positions.Any(o => o.Id== 5)) ?? new Position { Id = 5,   PositionName = "ABC" }

Application appOne = new Application
{
   Id = 8,
   ApplicationName = "AppOne",
   ApplicationPosotion = appPosotion  
};
```

Comment: The above still forces me to do the checking. I am looking for a way to just overwrite whatever value the child object has. More like Upsert

Comment: Aint that be `db.Positions.FirstOrDefault(o => o.Id== 5)) ??` instead of `.Any(` ?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for? Do an update of `ApplicationPosotion` without hitting the database for `Position` of the given id (here 5)?

```
var position = new Position { Id = 5};
db.Positions.Attach(position);

            Application appOne = new Application
            {
                Id = 8,
                ApplicationName = "AppOne",
                ApplicationPosotion = position
            };

            db.Applications.Add(appOne);
            db.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 0):

The above works. Here is my modified code.

```
                Application appOne = new Application
            {
                Id = 7,
                ApplicationName = "AppOne",
                ApplicationPosotion = new Position { Id = 5, PositionName = "123" }
            };

            db.Positions.AddOrUpdate(appOne.ApplicationPosotion);
            db.Applications.AddOrUpdate(appOne);
            db.SaveChanges();

            appOne = db.Applications.Find(7);
            Console.WriteLine(appOne.ApplicationPosotion.PositionName);
```

How ever is their a simple setting in EF that tells just do an Upsert ? Right now every object I have to break it down.

Comment: Your answer is correct. I am looking to see if we have an option we can set so I do not have to break every complex object. I am trying to do a ETL where I am getting different types of objects that I need to load into SQL server

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of 3 level deep

```
                Application appOne = new Application
            {
                Id = 7,
                ApplicationName = "AppOne",
                ApplicationPosition = new Position
                {
                    Id = 5,
                    PositionName = "123",
                    SalaryAmount = new Salary() { Id = 1, SalaryAmount = 200000 }
                }
            };

            db.Salarys.AddOrUpdate(appOne.ApplicationPosition.SalaryAmount);
            db.Positions.AddOrUpdate(appOne.ApplicationPosition);
            db.Applications.AddOrUpdate(appOne);
            db.SaveChanges();

            appOne = db.Applications.Find(7);
            Console.WriteLine(appOne.ApplicationPosition.SalaryAmount.SalaryAmount);
```

But I love to skip this step

```
          db.Salarys.AddOrUpdate(appOne.ApplicationPosition.SalaryAmount);
          db.Positions.AddOrUpdate(appOne.ApplicationPosition);
```

Because I do not want to set this up for every object.